# Can't load assets from facebook instant game bundle

Tags: phaser-framework, facebook-instant-games

Does anyone know is there way to load assets from facebook instant game bundle. I'm using a Phaser 3 to render and load any assets. When I open facebook instant game on "testing" status. I get an error in console `phaser.min.js:1 GET https://apps-[appid].apps.fbsbx.com/assets/example.png 404`
It's working perfectly on localhost using facebook embedded player

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when importing images i forgot to add "." in this.load.image function.

```
this.load.image("carPicture", "./assets/car.png");
```